# How to solve data type error using pickle and pandas udf for XGBoost model deployment python?

Tags: pickle

I have created a pandas udf() which splits dataset, fit XGBoost model, save it using pickle and returns a df with the saved model as a string column. The problem is when I call pandas udf(). It gives 'unsupported data type' error. But, when I run code without pandas udf() framework it runs successfully. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

@pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def pickle_model(df1):

```
X = df1.iloc[:,1:50] 
Y= df1.iloc[:,50] 
seed = 7 
test_size = 0.30 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

model = XGBClassifier(max_depth=3,...) 

eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)] 

model.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=8,...) 

model_str = pickle.dumps(model)

model_saved = pd.DataFrame([model_str],columns = ['model_str'])
return model_saved
```

pickled_model = df2.groupby('id').apply(pickle_model)
pickled_model.collect()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 691.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 691.0 (TID 38146, 10.139.64.9, executor 40): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported data type: struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>

Answer (score 0):

For dumping model pickle files use

```
model_str = str(pickle.dumps(model),'latin1')
```

And when loading back
use

```
pickle.loads(bytes(model_str,'latin1'))
```